# Symfony Doctrine schema update not working on MariaDB

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb

I have a database schema (partially) managed through Doctrine2 within a Symfony project.

When I make a copy of the database to my development machine:

```
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

,I have a range of queries to be run on \

```
doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

However, when I run the same command on the live server, which is

```
+----------------+
| version()      |
+----------------+
| 5.5.52-MariaDB |
+----------------+
```

no queries are shown at all.

The symfony project is managed with git and all files are in sync.

Is there an access right I'm missing?

Comment: Seems like that would dump only the table definitions, not the data; is this what you desire?

Comment: 5.5 is much older than 5.7; `CREATE TABLE` is _probably_ the same, but I would worry.

Comment: Just adjust your development machine to match your production server.  Life is too short to deal with stuff like this.  Of course you could always try clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Mysql5.6(Server) and Mysql5.7(local), and using DoctrineMigrations, migrations created local not working in the server. Then reading doctrine documentation y see the following option:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: 5.6
```

Then migrations are generated using mysql5.6 statements.

test using this option in your **config.yml**:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: 5.5
```